Capturing text selection in Google Docs for Chrome extension
I'm developing a Chrome extension that shows a popup when text is selected on web pages. It works fine on most websites, but I'm having issues with Google Docs. Here's the relevant part of my content script:


import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import PopupComponent from './popup'

let popupContainer = null

function showPopup(rect, selectedText) {
  if (!popupContainer) {
    popupContainer = document.createElement('div')
    document.body.appendChild(popupContainer)
  }

  const popupStyle = {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: `${rect.left}px`,
    top: `${rect.bottom + window.scrollY}px`,
    zIndex: 9999999999999999999,
  }

  const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(popupContainer)
  root.render(
    <div style={popupStyle}>
      <PopupComponent />
    </div>
  )
}

function hidePopup() {
  if (popupContainer) {
    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(popupContainer)
    root.unmount()
    // ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(popupContainer)
  }
}

function handleTextSelection() {
  const selectedText = window.getSelection().toString().trim()
  if (selectedText) {
    const range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)
    const rect = range.getBoundingClientRect()
    showPopup(rect, selectedText)
  } else {
    hidePopup()
  }
}

// Listen for text selection
document.addEventListener('mouseup', handleTextSelection)

// Listen for scroll events to reposition the popup
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const selection = window.getSelection()
  if (!selection.isCollapsed) {
    const range = selection.getRangeAt(0)
    const rect = range.getBoundingClientRect()
    showPopup(rect, selection.toString().trim())
  }
})

// Listen for clicks outside the popup to close it
document.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
  if (popupContainer && !popupContainer.contains(event.target)) {
    hidePopup()
  }
})

// Cleanup function
function cleanup() {
  document.removeEventListener('mouseup', handleTextSelection)
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleTextSelection)
  if (popupContainer) {
    document.body.removeChild(popupContainer)
  }
}

// Call cleanup when the content script is unloaded
window.addEventListener('unload', cleanup)



Problem is in this method:


function handleTextSelection() {
  const selectedText = window.getSelection().toString().trim()
  if (selectedText) {
    const range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)
    const rect = range.getBoundingClientRect()
    showPopup(rect, selectedText)
  } else {
    hidePopup()
  }
}

document.addEventListener('mouseup', handleTextSelection)



This works well on regular web pages, but in Google Docs, window.getSelection() returns an empty string. I suspect this is because Google Docs uses a canvas or some other technology that doesn't interact with the standard DOM selection API.
I've noticed that other extensions like Grammarly can successfully capture text selection in Google Docs. Is there a way to achieve this functionality?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. thanx!

Bro, Google uses redix-ui/primitive. Having a svg wrapped with div .kix-scrollareadocumentplugin .docs-ui-hit-region-surface. When triggered by a input It will scan the changes and displays it repeatedly. Hoping it might help you...

The reason that window.getSelection() returns an empty string on Google Docs is because Google uses a custom rendering method for its text. Try the following, which utilizes document.activeElement to get the content from Google Docs.
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import PopupComponent from './popup';

let popupContainer = null;

function showPopup(rect, selectedText) {
  if (!popupContainer) {
    popupContainer = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(popupContainer);
  }

  const popupStyle = {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: `${rect.left}px`,
    top: `${rect.bottom + window.scrollY}px`,
    zIndex: 9999999999999999999,
  };

  const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(popupContainer);
  root.render(
    <div style={popupStyle}>
      <PopupComponent text={selectedText} />
    </div>
  );
}

function hidePopup() {
  if (popupContainer) {
    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(popupContainer);
    root.unmount();
    document.body.removeChild(popupContainer);
    popupContainer = null;
  }
}

function getSelectedText() {
  const activeElement = document.activeElement;
  if (activeElement && activeElement.tagName === 'TEXTAREA') {
    return activeElement.value.substring(
      activeElement.selectionStart,
      activeElement.selectionEnd
    );
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    return window.getSelection().toString();
  }
  return '';
}

function handleTextSelection() {
  const selectedText = getSelectedText().trim();
  if (selectedText) {
    const range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    const rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
    showPopup(rect, selectedText);
  } else {
    hidePopup();
  }
}

document.addEventListener('mouseup', handleTextSelection);

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  if (!selection.isCollapsed) {
    const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    const rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
    showPopup(rect, selection.toString().trim());
  }
});

document.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
  if (popupContainer && !popupContainer.contains(event.target)) {
    hidePopup();
  }
});

document.addEventListener('copy', async () => {
  try {
    const clipboardData = await navigator.clipboard.readText();
    if (clipboardData) {
      showPopup(null, clipboardData);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Failed to read clipboard contents:', err);
  }
});

function cleanup() {
  document.removeEventListener('mouseup', handleTextSelection);
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleTextSelection);
  if (popupContainer) {
    document.body.removeChild(popupContainer);
  }
}

window.addEventListener('unload', cleanup);


Hi, i got one more thing, what is the best way to replace selected text in google docs?

@Nightcrawler I think its best to open a separate question for that. Did the following work for you?

not really, it's hard to detect text selection, found other approach which i am working on, will post update here

@Nightcrawler alright goodluck
